# Java generic type check for classes with two generic paramters should only hold classes of same type

Tags: java, generics

I have a situation where I want to compare a List of Pairs in Java. I'll be using this [Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)-interface from Apache.

A Pair's Left and Right value can be of a type that implements Comparable, so I declare the List as follows:

```
List<Pair<Comparable, Comparable>> listOfPairs;
```

The Left and Right value should always be of the same type, e.g. `Pair<String, String>` or `Pair<Integer, Integer>`, and both kinds of Pairs could be added to the same list.

This works:

```
    Pair<Comparable, Comparable> p1 = new ImmutablePair<>("a", "b");
    Pair<Comparable, Comparable> p2 = new ImmutablePair<>(2, 3);

    listOfPairs.add(p1);
    listOfPairs.add(p2);
```

This also works:

```
    Pair<Comparable, Comparable> p3 = new ImmutablePair<>("a", 2);
    listOfPairs.add(p3);
```

Is it possible to have a type check, to ensure that a Pair's types are of the same type, once it is added to the list, e.g. fail at compile time?

Comment: No, not by generics alone. You'd need to encapsulate the access to the list, and control the generic arguments in the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if that variable is a local variable, then you can add a type parameter to the method where it's declared.

```
public <T extends Comparable> void myMethod() {
    ...
    List<Pair<T, T>> listOfPairs;
    ...
```

If they're fields, you can add a type parameter to the class.

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable> {
    ...
    private List<Pair<T, T>> listOfPairs;
    ...
```

Another alternative, if neither of these suits your situation, is to define your own `Pair` generic class something like this with no members, then use it in place of `Pair` as required.  You'll need  to write a constructor in this class, which just delegates to the superclass constructor

```
public class SelfPair<T> extends Pair<T,T> {
    public SelfPair(T first, T second) {
        super(first, second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement your own class that either extends ImmutablePair or the Pair class.

example:

```
public class MyPair<T> extends Pair<Comparable<T>, Comparable<T>> {

public MyPair(T key, T value) {

}

}
```

When you create an instance of such class, the generic T type will always be the same for both arguments.